# how to extract the strings to resouce bundle from xhtml file with intellij idea

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, properties, xhtml, resourcebundle

Is there a way to extract the message strings into the resource bundle files while coding xhtml (jsf) files by using intellij idea?

I want to add the message properties by using refactoring option of intellij idea. For example; I have a string like "Hello" in my xhtml file. When I selected it  I want to extract this string to my bundle file automaticly.